# tcp_callback was never called in the sample of libnids

Tags: c, tcp, network-programming, pcap, libnids

I am working on extract http data from pcap file. I have to reassemble the fragment, so I find nids lib. I install libnids 1.24 with homebrew in Mac os 10.9.5 64bits.

I try to run the [printall sample](http://libnids.sourceforge.net/printall.c) . I modified the code a bit to suit my environment, such as changing "nids.h" to , add nids_params.filename = filename; to open offline file to analyze.

The sample is able to start. But the problem is it print nothing.

I add print to the first line of tcp_callback function. Again, nothing. That indicates the callback is never called.

To prove the problem is not relatted with my cap file

- I set it to capture live packet. After I open a webpage, I get nothing.
- I parse the pcap file with libpcap myself and get lots of tcp packet.
- the number of the packets is 70k+. It is unlikely there isn't a whole tcp connection with handshake.

It's such a pain to compile libnids with the sample and debug step by step. So can you give me some info about why the callback is not called?

Answer (score 3):

Since no one answered me :(  I have to choose the most painful way : compile libnids, then debug step by step to see wtf was going on.

I try turn off the -O2 compile options.

And see where the tcp callback should be called. I find that two facts:

- the checksum of some packets is wrong.
- it merely find a tcp stream and add a new connection because of ACKs' not being seen.

the first one is verified by wireshark. And I see wireshark nofify me that `tcp checksum offload`. I get the explaination from the wiki of wireshark:

> Most modern operating systems support some form of network offloading,
>   where some network processing happens on the NIC instead of the CPU.
>   Normally this is a great thing. It can free up resources on the rest
>   of the system and let it handle more connections. If you're trying to
>   capture traffic it can result in false errors and strange or even
>   missing traffic.
>         Checksum Offload
>        On systems that support checksum offloading, IP, TCP, and UDP checksums are calculated on the NIC just before they're transmitted on
>   the wire. In Wireshark these show up as outgoing packets marked black
>   with red Text and the note [incorrect, should be xxxx (maybe caused by
>   "TCP checksum offload"?)].

The second one is because libnids is able to reassemble the stream by the hand shake message.

All of a sudden, The idea come to my mind that combining these two fact result in the result output nothing.

**Since most ACKs packet have wrong checksum.** So the packet is skipped before it can be seen by the reassemble function.

After disable checksum, I finally get the output of tcp payload. Two days and I got it!