# Libnids: Infinite loop in TCP Reassembly

Tags: ubuntu, tcp, libnids

I am trying to run [this code](https://libnids.sourceforge.net/printall.c) for Libnids library using these commands:

```
gcc -o myprog reassemble.c -lnids -lglib-2.0 -lpcap -lnet -lgthread-2.0 -g
sudo ./myprog
```

But it does not give any output. It acts like there are no captured packets on the provided network device, Although when I tried to capture packets separately, it works fine and packets are captured.

When I debug the code, it seems like the callback function is not called at all.
By the way, I have tried the same code by registering UDP callback function instead, and it worked.

Does anyone suggest a solution for the problem? and Is there any other library to reassembly TCP packets in c language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27277580/tcp-callback-was-never-called-in-the-sample-of-libnids/27311417#27311417), I have found the solution.
I have used the following command:

```
ethtool -K <device_name> tx off sg off tso off
```

to disable TSO for a network device <device_name>, and it worked!